# ReferenceError: Image is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, image, constructor

I am trying to make a website, in which I include images via links. If an image is non-existent, or just 1 pixel wide, the website should display an alternative image. I am using Jade/Pug and JS.

I try to make a list of links beforehand, before rendering them on the website. That way I can just iterate threw my link-list in the .pug file afterwards.
So what I am trying to do is, to check, if an image has a certain size, using JS only. If it does, I add the link to my list, if not, then I add an alternative link.

This is the important part of my code in the app.js-file:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    //get all the books
    var isbns = [];
    var links = [];
    dbClient.query("SELECT isbn FROM book WHERE id < 20", function (dbError, dbItemsResponse){
        isbns = dbItemsResponse.rows;
        var linkk = 0;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++){
            linkk = "http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/" + Object.values(isbns[i]) + "-M.jpg";
            var wid = getMeta(linkk);
               if(wid < 2){
                    links[i]="https://i.ibb.co/7JnVtcB/NoCover.png";
                } else {
                    links[i]=linkk;
                }
            }

    });
});

function getMeta(url){   
    var img = new Image(); //or document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = function(){
        alert(this.width);
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

This gives me a ReferenceError: Image() is not defined. If I try to use document.createElement("img"); it says "document is not defined".
How can i check on the server-side if an Image is existent? Or how can I use the Image-Constructor in my app.js file? Without using my Jade/Pug/HTML file in any way.
Sorry If it's a dumb question, but I am trying to figure this out since 20 hours non-stop, and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing up `nodejs` and `javascript`. Your code is `nodejs` and therefor on the sererside. `window` and `Image` are only available in the browser, resp. on the client side.

For checking if a file exists, (Only on the serverside!=) you can use `fs` => [fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback).

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// Check if the file exists
fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK, err => {
  console.log(file, err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the Canvas npm package allows you to use the Image constructor as desired. I've found cases where this is essential, like in server-side image processing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

`npm install canvas`

```
import { Image } from "canvas";

const img = new Image;
```